Displaying elements problem in JSF/Facelets file
I write code in JSF/Facelets file to show a form but it did not show anything.
Here's my surveyform.xhtml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<f:view>
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:graphicImage alt="There is error" name="form-icon.jpg" library="image"/>
            <h1>Khảo sát</h1>
            <img src="resources/image/form.png" alt="This is error" style="width: 30px; height: 30px"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputLabel value="Họ tên"/>
            <h:inputText id="txtHoTen"/>
            <h:outputLabel value="Năm sinh"/>
            <h:inputText id="txtNamSinh"/>
            <h:selectOneRadio id="rdoGioiTinh">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="Nam" itemLabel="Nam"/>
                <f:selectItem itemValue="Nữ" itemLabel="Nữ"/>
            </h:selectOneRadio>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</f:view>
</html>

I tried to use <h:graphicImage>, <h:panelGrid>, <h:outputLabel>, ... before but it did not display anything. Otherwise, html tags like <h1> or <img> still work fine. So what happened? Why facelets component code can not run?
I searched and chatGPT said that I need to add following code to my web.xml file:
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

But when I added this to my file, my glassfish server even did not run properly, there was an error during artifact deployment (my war file got in trouble). I looked at log and see this error:

Artifact surveywebapp:war exploded: java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDI is not available

